# adding "5" to INT

Tags: php, mysql

So now when I get points from DB, I want to add 5 points to [points] and save to DB:

```
function addPoints($email)
{
    $con = mysql_connect("example", "example", "example") ;
    if (!$con)
    {
        die("Can not connected: " . mysql_error());
    }
    mysql_select_db("example",$con);
    $sql = "SELECT points FROM tablename WHERE email = '$email'";
    $myData = mysql_query($sql,$con);
    while($record = mysql_fetch_array($myData))
    {
        $record['points'];      
    }
    mysql_close($con);
}
```

Comment: **warning** your code maybe vulnerable to sql injection attacks!

Comment: Don't use the mysql extension, use PDO or mysqli. And use prepared statements.

Comment: If the value of email is user input then it *is* vulnerable to SQLi.

Comment: Go with PDO or MySQLi.

Comment: You can try to write this update query instead of your sql query: "UPDATE tablename SET points = " . $yourPoints + 5 . " WHERE email = '$email'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish the same with `UPDATE` query

```
UPDATE tablename SET points = points + 5 WHERE email = 'your_email_here'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$newPoints = $record['points'] + 5;
$sql = "UPDATE tablename SET points = '$newPoints' WHERE email = '$email'";
mysql_query($sql,$con);
```

Comment: You also need to look at: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

Answer (score 0):

You can modify you while loop to achieve that.

```
while($record = mysql_fetch_array($myData)){
    $points = $record['points'];    
$query = "update tablename set points=". $points +5 ." WHERE email = '$email'";
mysql_query($query, $con);      
}
```